# Why does Linq does not order my result immediately

Tags: c#, linq

Running the following sort on a list. Path entity is a custom class. MinMax is two points the represent a rectangle in 2D space. MinMax.Min.X is the lower rectangle 2D point x value. X is a double.

```
List<IPathEntity> sortedByMinX = (from e in entities
                                    orderby e.MinMax.Min.X ascending
                                    select e).ToList();
```

MinMax property is retrieved every time it is accessed from a list of Points it is called by doing:

```
   public MinMax MinMax
    {
        get
        {
            if (Points.Any())
            {
                double minX = (from p in Points
                               select p.X).Min();
                double minY = (from p in Points
                               select p.Y).Min();
                double maxX = (from p in Points
                               select p.X).Max();
                double maxY = (from p in Points
                               select p.Y).Max();
                return new MinMax(new Point3d(minX, minY, 0), new Point3d(maxX, maxY, 0));
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is the linq sort runs but the values are not ordered by the MinMax.Min.X value. If I do the following I get the original list order:

```
foreach (var item in sortedByMinX)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(item.MinMax.ToString());
}
```

Result (The Min.X and Max.X is listed first then the Min.Y, Max.Y:

```
X's:249.38, 264.31 ... Y's:37.41, 41.61
X's:249.38, 264.31 ... Y's:171.41, 175.61
X's:249.38, 264.31 ... Y's:104.41, 108.61
X's:137.29, 194.22 ... Y's:18.2, 35.55
X's:165.59, 248.07 ... Y's:12.16, 39.89
X's:251.3, 348.91 ... Y's:10.17, 15.79
...
```

If I then use the MinMax.Min.X to output:

```
foreach (var item in sortedByMinX)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(item.MinMax.Min.X.ToString());
}
```

The list appears ordered by that value:
137.29
137.29
137.29
165.59
165.59
165.59
173.3
173.3
173.3
209.72
...

If I then use the original output foreach loop again:

```
foreach (var item in sortedByMinX)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(item.MinMax.ToString());
}
```

The list is now outputs sorted as expected:

```
X's:137.29, 194.22 ... Y's:152.2, 169.55
X's:137.29, 194.22 ... Y's:85.1999999999999, 102.55
X's:137.29, 194.22 ... Y's:18.2, 35.55
X's:165.59, 248.07 ... Y's:146.16, 173.89
X's:165.59, 248.07 ... Y's:79.16, 106.89
X's:165.59, 248.07 ... Y's:12.16, 39.89
...
```

It's like the list is not actually sorted until I access the same property that it was sorted by. There must be something I don't understand about Linq?

What is happening here and how can I get the sorted list from the linq without iterating the list after I execute the linq?

Comment: Could you provide a [mvce]? (Ideally simplified as far as possible from your current code.) I'd normally expect this to work fine... I suspect something odd is going on. As an aside, all of your Min/Max calculations can be simplified, e.g. `double minX = Points.Min(p => p.X);`

Comment: Could you provide full MinMax code ? (it seems that Min is a calculated property, it might be the problem)

Comment: By any chance are you changing the `Points` between running the query and iterating over it?  If so you should not use `ToList` so that those changes will be reflected each time you iterate the query.

Comment: @juharr - No possibility that the Points values are changing.

Comment: @JonSkeet - [mvce] is going to be difficult. Maybe 1/2 day just to put it together. I'll see what I can do. Maybe doing that I can find what it is by removing pieces as I simplify?

Comment: @EricSnyder That is sometimes a happy by-product of reducing the code to a [mcve], yes :)

Answer (score 0):

I changed the property MinMax to look like this:

```
public MinMax MinMax { get; set; }
```

I then added a AddPoint Method that looks like this:

```
public void AddPoint(Point3d point)
{
    points.Add(point);
    MinMax.Min.X = Points.Min(p => p.X);
    MinMax.Min.Y = Points.Min(p => p.Y);
    MinMax.Max.X = Points.Max(p => p.X);
    MinMax.Max.Y = Points.Max(p => p.Y);
}
```

Resolved the issue. @SunPaz was right...somehow the MinMax being calculated was the issue.

Comment: I'd still be interested to see where... if you *can* find time to isolate this as a minimal example, I suspect it will benefit your project in the long run.